# chrome 25 iframe customize protocol don' twork

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, protocol-handler

i have protocol (like http) with scheme managed with 3rd party App registered in android. I.e,someapp://someaction or something like that.

before upgrade chrome to latest version(chrome 25), it works fine, but after upgrade, it don't worked.

i just use iframe to try load the registered app.
here is my code snapshot.

```
<iframe src="about:blank" id="myframe"/>
<script>
  function changesrc(){
    document.getElementById("myframe").src="someapp://someaction"
  }
</script>
```

any ideas for this issue??

Answer (score 2):

We believe this is a potential for a security or malicious action bug and will not be implementing it in Chrome any longer.  See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169204#c27 for more details.

There is a solution, you can construct a [special "intent" url](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents) that the user can invoke.

The basic syntax for an intent based URI is as follows:

```
“intent:”
    HOST/URI-path “;”  // Optional
        “#Intent;”
        package=[string];
        action=[string];
        category=[string];
        component=[string];
                    scheme=[string];
    “;end”
```

Parsing details available in the Android source.

To launch the Zxing barcode scanner app you can encode your href as follows intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end in an href on the anchor as follows
 Take a qr code

Extracted from : https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml#97

The android manifest defines the scheme to be “zxing”, the package to be “com.google.zxing.client.android” and the host data to be “scan”
When the user clicks on this link they will taken straight to the app if they already have it installed, or if not directly to the play store.

Comment: When using this approach, is it possible to pass to specify a referrer similar to the way you can append "&referrer=[whatever]" when linking to the app store?

Comment: @LukeMelia I am investigating.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a requirement that would be important to Google, and certainly is important to our usage of the old style.

Comment: Were you able to find anything out about this?

Comment: @LukeMelia I haven't been able to find anything specific, for example if you install the app, the original intent is not re-invoked either.